# What is the purpose of using a FIFO vs a temporary file or a pipe?

Tags: pipe, fifo, ipc, mkfifo

From APUE

> FIFOs can be used to **duplicate an output stream in a series of shell
>   commands**. This **prevents writing the data to an intermediate disk
>   ﬁle** (similar to using pipes to avoid intermediate  disk  ﬁles).
>
> But  whereas  pipes  can  be  used  only  for  linear  connections
>   between processes, a FIFO has a name, so it can be used for
>   **nonlinear connections**.
>
> Consider  a  procedure that  needs  to  process  a  ﬁltered  input 
>   stream  twice.
>
> ```
> mkfifo fifo1
> prog3 < fifo1 &
> prog1 < infile | tee fifo1 | prog2
> ```
>
> We create the FIFO and then start prog3 in the background, reading
>   from the FIFO. We then  start prog1 and  use tee to  send  its  input 
>   to  both  the  FIFO  and prog2.

1. How does a FIFO "duplicate an output stream in a series of shell commands"? Isn't this done by `tee` instead of a FIFO?
2. In the example, `mkfifo fifo1` creates a file in the current directory, and `fifo1` seems replaceable with a regular file . So what is the point of a FIFO "prevent writing the data to an intermediate disk file"?
3. What do "linear connections" and "nonlinear connections" between processes mean? What does it mean that a FIFO can be used for nonlinear connections, while a pipe can be only used for linear connections between processes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

1. APUE says “FIFOs **can be used** to duplicate an output stream”, it doesn’t say that FIFOs actually duplicate the output stream. As you point out, the duplication is done by `tee` in the example.
2. `mkfifo` creates a FIFO, which is visible as a “file” in the containing directory; but writing to the FIFO isn’t like writing to a file because the data never hits the disk. Pipes, named or otherwise, don’t provide storage for data, they provide communications channels; the writing end of a pipe can’t write data if there’s no receiver, the pipe just passes data along, without storing it. (On most systems pipes *are* backed by small kernel buffers, to improve performance, but that’s an implementation detail.)
3. Linear connections between processes are pipes which can be represented as a linear graph. In the example, you can represent the last line as

   ```
   infile → prog1 → tee fifo1 → prog3
   ```

   which is linear, but if you try to represent the whole chain, reducing to processing elements, you need

   ```
   infile → prog1 → prog2
                  → prog3
   ```

   which is non-linear (there’s one node in the graph, `prog1`, which has two exit nodes).

Comment: Thanks. (2) What is the advantage of a FIFO over a temporary regular file? (3) The nonlinear connection between processes is actually implemented by `tee`, not by a FIFO, for example, using `tee` and a temporary regular file we can achieve the same nonlinear connection too.

Comment: The description in APUE opposes FIFOs and files on the one hand, FIFOs and pipes on the other; you can’t conflate the three. When comparing FIFOs and files, the difference is that FIFOs don’t involve hitting the disk *for the content written to the FIFO* (this addresses your point 2). When comparing FIFOs and pipes, the difference is that FIFOs are named so they can be used in places pipes can’t. APUE doesn’t say you can’t use files to implement non-linear connections, it just says you can’t use pipes.

Comment: Thanks. What is the advantage of "don’t involve hitting the disk for the content written to the FIFO"?

Comment: Disks are slow. (At least, they were when APUE was written.)

Comment: Thanks. Besides speed, I am also wondering about space. Do named pipes (as used in FIFO and process substitution) reside in main memory? Does a named pipe have to hold all the content as a temporary file in disk  when using the file instead of a named pipe? Does the main memory  have to be large enough if the content is huge?

Comment: A pipe (FIFO or whatever) doesn’t hold data, it transfers data between processes. You can see this by running, for example, `mkfifo fifo && seq 1 1000000 | tee fifo`. You won’t see any input from this initially, because the FIFO doesn’t start accepting data until both its ends are open. Run `head fifo`, and you’ll see the `seq` side of the pipe output a bunch of numbers and then stop with exit code 141, *i.e.* `SIGPIPE` (128 + 13): the output gives an indication the size of the kernel buffer used for the FIFO, at most a few tens of kilobytes. That’s all the memory that’s used by a pipe.

Comment: By the way, in your last example that `prog1` needs two exit nodes (one for `prog2` and one for `prog3`), someone can use `tee` under some circumstances like this:  `echo "hello world" | tee >(sed 's/h/H/') >(sed 's/w/W/g')`

Comment: BTW: The limitation of anonymous pipes being useful only for linear connections is really a limit of shell pipeline syntax; the `pipe` syscall has no such limitation.